# Unable to uninstall Wine apps

Tags: wine, uninstall

I recently ran the iTunes 10 installer in Wine and everything seemed to go well. Then, when I tried to run it, it would constantly crash/and the appearance would be glitchy. After looking at the Wine website, it turns out that iTunes 10 has a 'garbage' rating of Wine compatability.

Now I'm trying to remove/uninstall iTunes, QuickTime, and the other applications that come default with installing iTunes (such as Bonjour, etc.).
However, when I run the 'uninstaller' that wine provides for the programs, it instead executes what appears to actually be the original installer!
I've tried deleting all the configuration/data files in my Wine's file-system, but to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit1:
After re-running the uninstall process and then rebooting, the program (iTunes 10) still remained installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wine apps often leave a lot of junk, for example, menu items over .doc files after installing Microsoft Office. To remove it, you have to:

```
rm .local/share/applications/wine-extension-*
```

To remove menu entries you have to edit:

```
usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

And, right click on file you want to remove bad menu entries from, and choose Properties. On the 4th tab you can delete unnecessary entries.

Comment: Thank you sir! This has solved the issue. If I had enough reputation I would vote up your answer. :(
I will come back as soon as I have enough and do just that.

Answer (score 11):

### How do I uninstall *all* Windows applications?

To remove all programs installed under Wine, remove the wineprefix (usually the ~/.wine directory) by carefully pasting the following commands into a terminal:

```bash
cd $HOME
rm -rf .wine
```

But that doesn't remove them from the system menu. To clean out the menus, carefully paste the following commands into a terminal:

```bash
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.{xpm,png}
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/*-x-wine-*.{xpm,png}
```

---

After all that, right-click on the top panel and select Edit Menus:

[image: contextual menu from right-clicking top panel, showing Help, Edit Menus, Remove From Panel, Move, and Lock To Panel, with Move grayed out and Lock To Panel checked]

Then go to the Others tab and delete all the Microsoft Office launchers. (Or they might be in some other location, just search.)

Comment: I did just that but The entries are still there in open with dialog. Any idea why?

Comment: edited my answer, just check if it works

Comment: Wow, that did it! For those using unity, the program to do that is called alacarte and can be searched in dash
Thank you gazillion Ashu!

Comment: What do you mean "top panel"?