# I uninstalled wine thinking the Windows apps would go with it but they didn't and now they are stuck on my PC!

Tags: wine, software-uninstall

I uninstalled wine thinking the Windows apps I'd installed would uninstall with it but they didn't and now they're stuck on the PC.

I tried installing wine again but now they don't show in the add/remove program tab. I should mention that one of the games I installed, Far Cry 2 (which did not work at all) gave me an error when I tried to uninstall it. That was the reason for uninstalling wine in the first place, as I thought it would remove the game with it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Too anyone else who has this issue I found my solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5724/unable-to-uninstall-wine-apps ...hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to delete the `~/.wine` folder from your system. You can do that with:

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
```

but be sure to make a back up, as the `rm` command can be dangerous.

Comment: `rm` is a little safer without the `-f` argument.  Of course the `-f` can save a lot of time when you're sure of the action.